# custom template display 3 columns

Tags: css

I create a custom template this the code and I want in result 3 columns and the side bar on the right. I try with css something like that

```
.grid-container{
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 20px 20px;
}
```

but I don't have the 3 column and the side bar is broken
this page is for display custom post for the exemple I just put the title and the image.
If someone have a solution could help
thank you

```
<?php
/** Template Name: New Release image side bar */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'movie'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="grid-container">
            <div class ="column">
            <div class="img_gallery">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div
            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
            
            </div></div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi g rom, it looks more like a CSS question not WP so probably this is not the best place to ask.

Comment: Hi thank you for your observation

Answer (score 0):

Check with below code you need to start that `grid-container` div before `while loop` as like below:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'movie'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<div class="grid-container">
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class ="column">
            <div class="img_gallery">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div
            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
            
            </div></div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

try with you get result what you wants.